# Secure Implementation of Network Discovery Tool in Corporate Network

Tags: network, firewalls, network-scanners

I would like to implement a network discovery tool, which automatically detects all devices in a network including OS information. I would like to do a very secure implementation. The biggest threat in the eyes of my colleagues are the insecure firewall rules this kind of tools needs and the privileged user. They are arguing a hacked networking discovery tool could act like a jump host, because it can communicate in all networks, even DMZ. So for the user I already found a solution: I will use a really low privileged User. However, for the insecure firewall rules I'm kind of clueless. I was thinking about temporary firewall rules and performing the discovery jobs in the time frame in which these rules are activated. Is this useful? Is the risk even relevant? Does anybody have any resources, experiences on how to implement this kind of software as secure as you can. I didn't find anything useful on the internet.

Comment: What do you want to be able to discover? Unmanaged machines? Why not use agents on the managed machines and network info for unmanaged machines? Why are firewall rules a problem?